# Can \relax be replaced by a space?

Tags: macros, tex-core

LaTeX defines `\vec` as

```
\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{letters}{"7E}
```

which eventually is expanded to

```
\mathaccent"017E\relax
```

whereas plainTeX defines it as

```
\def\vec{\mathaccent"017E }
```

replacing `\relax` with a space.

Is there any practical difference?

Comment: Most of the time a space will work, but \relax will always work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for `\mathaccent` is (TeXbook, p. 291)

> `\mathaccent`⟨15-bit number⟩⟨math field⟩

A ⟨15-bit number⟩ is an integer (in any denotation allowed by LaTeX) in the range 0–2<sup>15</sup>. What's a ⟨math field⟩? We find it on page 289

> ⟨math field⟩ → ⟨filler⟩⟨math symbol⟩ | ⟨filler⟩`{`⟨math mode material⟩`}`

A ⟨filler⟩ is any sequence of space tokens and `\relax` tokens which are ignored (doing expansion) when processing the input stream looking for something that fits the syntax rule.

Thus in LaTeX the `\relax` will be gobbled as a ⟨filler⟩, whereas in plain TeX the space terminates the specification for the number and is ignored as well.

Why does LaTeX use `\relax`? The answer is in the definition of `\DeclareMathAccent` that internally uses `\set@mathaccent`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 3596:
\def\set@mathaccent#1#2#3#4{%
  \xdef#2{\mathaccent"\mathchar@type#3\hexnumber@#1#4\relax}}
```

The choice might depend on the fact that when writing to an auxiliary file `\relax` is better suited to the job.